# Update state through an ajax request but state is still undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am updating a state through an ajax request to the server. I am receiving data from the server but the state doesn't update for some reason and shows up as undefined when I try to iterate the array.

```
class TodoList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: undefined
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    request
      .get('http://localhost:8080/api/todo')
      .end(function(err, res) {
        this.setState({data: res});
      }.bind(this));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Todo Items</h1>
        <ul>
          {this.states.data.map((item) => {
            return <li>item.data</li>
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Console Logs

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made an syntax error with `this.state` in render method and with default value in `this.state.data`

```js
class TodoList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    /*request
      .get('http://localhost:8080/api/todo')
      .end(function(err, res) {
        this.setState({data: res});
      }.bind(this));*/
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Todo Items</h1>
        <ul>
          {this.state.data.map((item) => {
            return <li>item.data</li>
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <TodoList />,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" />
```

---

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a typo, change:

```
{this.states.data.map((item) => {
  return <li>item.data</li>
})}
```

To:

```
{this.state.data.map((item) => {
  return <li>item.data</li>
})}
```

Also, before your data is fetched, `state.data` is `undefinded` and it has no method `.map()`.
Change it to an empty array:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    data: undefined
  }
}
```

to:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
  }
}
```

Comment: Now its says `Uncaught TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function`

Comment: Have you changed `this.state = {
      data: undefined
    }` to `this.state = {
      data: []
  }` ? If yes, than provide please the result you get from the server.

Comment: This is the response I am getting `Response {req: Request, xhr: XMLHttpRequest, text: "[{"_id":"57a1d7606920c29a9d61cb40","author":"sffsg…or":"dsdsdsdsd7","title":"Buy a baloon","__v":0}]", statusText: "OK", statusCode: 200…}`

Comment: Try to change `this.setState({data: res});` to `this.setState({data: res.text})`

Comment: Thanks for that. But `res.text` is of type string but I want to be an array

Comment: You have to parse it with: `this.setState({data: JSON.parse(res.text)})`